# Drop off in open rates since using new template

Tags: marketing-cloud

Recently implemented a new master template in SFMC at work and since we have started to use this we have noticed a big drop in open rates - up to 40% drop off compared to the old templates when we have run A/B tests

We have checked the tracking coding is in the HTML and not broken
No major flags when run through Litmus
Contact lists haven't changed
Deliverability looks fine when using Everest/Validity

We have even seen occasions when the Unique click rate is higher than unique opens so we're certain more people are getting these emails than are being reported back.

Any ideas what could be causing this?

Comment: If 40% of your newsletter recipients are iphone users with ios15, it may have nothing to do with your template. iOs 15 blocks stuff like open tracking pixels.

Comment: Thanks! A few colleagues have mentioned ios but we have the tracking pixel on the old template too and that's seen no drop in open rates in the last 6 months or so

Comment: did the open rate go down while the click rate stayed comparable to your "old" sendouts? If clicks also went down, you might have a deliverability issue, if not then that indeed sounds rather unlikely.

Comment: It sounds like you have Litmus. Did you add Litmus tracking pixel to the emails as well? It might be interesting to compare the open numbers.

Comment: unique clicks were comparable but open rate dropped.
Deliverability looked ok as we had this checked using https://www.validity.com/everest/
We are just going through a  trial with Litmus but will soon add that pixel too for extra analytics

Comment: Another idea is that a firewall software developer or hardware developer changed something and blocks Salesforce open tracking. But this would likely be observed by more ppl. By the way this topic has great personas working on It with Lukas and Jonas. Cheers mates, keep up your amazing work

Comment: Did the placement of the pixel change? ie at the bottom vs the top, is the email longer/bigger?

Comment: HI @EazyE, we just checked that and it looks like the code is the exact same and in the same location as it is in the old templates so we can rule that one out too! Thanks

Comment: We've run another A/B test with results as below
Old Template 
Emails sent 2,047
CTR 2.4%
Open rate Deliverability 99.2%
 
New template
Emails sent 2,047
CTR 2.3%
Open rate 26.1%
Deliverability rate 99.3%